# Add Video in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, video, razor

I am working in ASP.NET MVC. I want to add videos in my view. I have read article on [Working With Videos in ASP.NET](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/files,-images,-and-media/10-working-with-video)

But i want a generic way to play all type of videos in my web page. This article, although good, but confuses me that how to identify file format and then use related type of Web Helper. There are hundreds of video file formats, how to play all of them, by a single strategy. Mentioned article only describes three formats. Please guide me in this regard.

Comment: Tell me a generic way to play all sort of videos please.

Comment: I'm afraid you cannot play all type of videos. Video format support is up to the plugin you choose to use.

Comment: Then how to get rid of this problem?

Comment: Maybe you can rely on http://malsup.com/jquery/media/ ?

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is less ASP.NET MVC and more general video playback accross multiple devices in different formats.

Your best option would be to use something like [FlowPlayer](http://flowplayer.org/), which allows you to add a player using either Flash or HTML5/JS (depending on the browser's feature set)

Answer (score 1):

I think to say you want to play all types of videos is the wrong way to start.  First of all I would think about what video types you want to support.  This can be restricted by things such as the encoded videos available, file size, browser support.

Once you have decided on this you can look in to finding the most suitable player for the job.